# VBA SQL statement run time error 91

Tags: sql, vba

I keep getting run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set. 
I have rs and strQuery as global variables, this is just a snipet of code not the entire thing. Can someone help me out with troubleshooting this?

```
Dim strQuery
Global db As DAO.Database
Global rs As DAO.Recordset 
strQuery = "SELECT courses.[CourseCode] as CODE, " & _
           "courses.[CourseName] as NAME " & _
           "FROM courses;"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery) 'error here
```

Comment: First step to fixing a code issue - identify what line it's on (I guess the last posted line). Next step for this error is hover over all of your variables and find the one that is 'nothing' (in your code it would be both `rs` and `db`, but the issue is with `db`

Answer (score 0):

db is not pointing to anything - you need to assign that to something.

E.g.

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
```